# Webbrowser control no longer working after Windows Update

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control

I have a custom project in VB6, which I was working with it since 3-4 years ago, now today suddenly I noticed that Webbrowser controls are not working anymore on my laptop (maybe after a windows automatic update - it's working on my other laptop)

The problem is when I double-click on Webbrowser components there are no default declarations for them and this text shows up in code section:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_SHDocVwCtl(ByVal Text As String)

End Sub
```

Please help me fix it and get it back to how it was before.

Comment: Maybe you need to recompile application and link binary with newest Windows API.

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: and it's not .exe file, I'm working directly in vb6 environment by pressing F5

Comment: Welcome @GabrielSalazar.  When you say it's not working, has it disappeared?  Go into Project > Components  and on that screen do you see "Microsoft Internet Controls" checked?

Comment: I just loaded up an old project with that control and the Javascript support I think goes back to Windows XP...  Is it using .Navigate to go to a site in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JimmySmith suggests, check that **Microsoft Internet Controls** is checked in your Components list (Project > Components > Controls tab > Microsoft Internet Controls.). If not, check it and hit Apply, then OK.

If it doesn't show up in the list, you can use the Browse button to look for `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ieframe.dll` directly.

Other things that I recommend:

1. Run VB6 IDE as Administrator. Right-click on your Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 shortcut and check "Run this program as an administrator" in compatibility properties section.
2. Select Windows XP (Service pack 3) as Compatibility mode.